# Display a div on button click

Tags: javascript

I have a div, whose display is set to none. On button click, I need to show this div.
I have wrote a JavaScript function to do so, and it works but on click of the button the div is shown and again it hides. What is to be done additionally so that is remains.

JavaScript is as follows:

```
function show_popup() {
    document.getElementById("Div1").style.display = 'block';
}
```

And div is as follows:

```
<div id="Div1" style="display:none">
```

The JavaScript function is called on button click as follows:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server"  OnClientClick="javascript: show_popup()"  Text="Button" />
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Do you need to do it on serverside or clientside?

Comment: the div is displayed and it hides again.It is visible only for few seconds

Comment: java script will be called on client side right?

Comment: Because the style="display:none" hides it.

Comment: yes so how to handle it?

Comment: how hide it initially and then display on button click?

Comment: The button click will post back to the server and reload the page. Do you _want_ the page to be submitted or just have the popup show?

Comment: First of all however most ASP.NET Developers I met do that, never do manipulations on interface using serverside process using AJAX. If you want to hide the div just do it using JavaScript. You do not need <asp:button> and runat="server" property of it. Simply create a button using html <button> or input type="button" tag and do the rest using only javascript. It will be easier, simpler and good.

Comment: I need to submit the page as the details from database will be displayed in the hidden div which will be displayed then.

Comment: Ok so i need to use AJAX you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Javascript is working, the Problem seems to be the Button implemented with ASP.

The Problem could be the Serversided implementation of the Button, here is the HTML implementation. Things are working there.

```js
function show_popup() {

         document.getElementById("Div1").style.display = 'block';
     }
```

```html
 


<div id="Div1" style="display:none">asdasdasdasdasdasd</div>


<input type="button" onclick="show_popup()" value="Show"></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret your question correctly: the `div` resets to be hidden on page refresh or navigation. This is to be expected, the display value should be handled on the server side too.

As others have said, the problem is that when you click on the button, the page is posted to the server. If you do not want to do this, you should use a normal HTML button (with `type="button"`), instead of an ASP one.