# How can I show the output vertically after submitting the html form?

Tags: php, html

[image: This is the screenshot of the output I am getting]

The who;e sequence(having operands , opertors and answer) in output is  generating randomly which is perfect. but I want to show that in vertical manner
and this is the output I want to show after clicking on generate
[image: the expected output based on screenshot]
 then Q(2)will show up  in the same way but after Q(1).

this is my html form.

```
    <form action="" method="POST">
              <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-25">
                   <label for="qnum">Select no.of questions:</label>
                    </div>
                     <div class = "col-75"><input type="number" id="qnum" name="que" value="1"  min="1" max="100"></div>
                     <br /><br />
               </div>
             <br />

        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-25">
                <label for="int">How many numbers You want in a sequence:</label></div>
                    <div class="col-75">
                       <select name="select" id="int">
                        <option value="2"> 2 </option>
                        <option value="3"> 3 </option>
                        <option value="4"> 4 </option>
                        <option value="5"> 5 </option>
                        <option value="6"> 6 </option>
                        <option value="7"> 7 </option>
                        <option value="8"> 8 </option>
                        <option value="9"> 9 </option>
                        <option value="10"> 10 </option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
      </div>
      <br /> 

       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-25">
             <label for="dig">Select no. of digits:</label></div>
                <div class="col-75">
                  <select name="digits" id="dig">
                   <option value="1"> 1 digit</option>
                   </select>
              </div>
              <br /><br /><br /><br />
        </div>

          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-25"><label>Select operations:</label><br /></div>
              <div class="col-75">
                <input type="checkbox" id="mix" value="all" class="toggle-button"><label>All</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="add" name="operation[]" value="Addition" checked><label>Addition</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="sub" name="operation[]" value="Subtraction"><label>Subtraction</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="mult" name="operation[]" value="Multiplication"><label>Multiplication</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="div" name="operation[]" value="Division"><label>Division</label>
               </div>
                <br /><br />
                <br /><br />
            </div><br />


        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate"><br>
         <br />

 </form>
   </div>
      <!---Toggle button to select all operations if user select checkbox named "All" -->
           <script language="JavaScript">
                $( '.col-75 .toggle-button' ).click( function () {
                $( '.col-75 input[type="checkbox"]' ).prop('checked', this.checked)
      })
          </script>
```

Basically I generating a random sequence of arithmetic expressions which is working perfectly without any error. 
But after clicking generate button the output is showing horizontally and I want to generate it vertically. 
So how can I do that?

Below is my php code which is generating the sequence perfectly without any error. How can I generate the output vertically?

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
       //validation for no of operation selected
       $operation = $_POST['operation'];
       if(empty($operation)) 
             {
               echo "Please Select at least one operation <br/>";
             }
              else
              {  
                 $N = count($operation); //count selected operation
                    echo  "<br />";
                     echo "You have selected $N operation(s):"; 

                            for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)  //for loop for for operator array.
                               {
                                  echo($operation[$i] . ", "); //display selected operation
                               }
                               echo "<br />";
                     //checkbox operations
                    if($N==1)   //if only one operation is selected
                        {
                             if($operation[0]=='Addition')
                                 {
                                      $rOperators = array('+');                           
                                 }
                                else if($operation[0]=='Subtraction')
                                   {
                                      $rOperators = array('-');
                                    }
                                    else if($operation[0]=='Multiplication')
                                      {
                                      $rOperators = array('*');
                                       }
                                        else
                                          {
                                            $rOperators = array('/');
                                          }
                        }
                    else if ($N==2) //if only two operations are selected by the user
                     {
                        if($operation[0]=='Addition')
                            {
                                if($operation[1]=='Subtraction')
                                    {
                                        $rOperators = array('+','-');
                                    }
                                     else if($operation[1]=='Multiplication')
                                         {
                                           $rOperators = array('+','*');
                                         }
                                          else
                                             {
                                               $rOperators = array('+','/');
                                             }                           
                            }
                            else if($operation[0]=='Subtraction')
                            {
                                if($operation[1]=='Multiplication')
                                     {
                                        $rOperators = array('-','*');
                                     }
                                    else
                                      {
                                        $rOperators = array('-','/');
                                      }
                            }
                              else
                                {
                                  $rOperators = array('*','/');
                                }
                      }
                        else if ($N==3) //if 3 operators gets selected by user
                            {
                                if($operation[0]=='Addition')
                                 {
                                     if($operation[1]=='Subtraction')
                                         {
                                             if($operation[2]=='Multiplication')
                                             {
                                                 $rOperators = array('+','-','*');    
                                             }
                                             else
                                             {
                                                 $rOperators = array('+','-','/');
                                             }

                                         }
                                      else
                                         {
                                              $rOperators = array('+','*','/');
                                         }                         
                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                     $rOperators = array('-','*','/');
                                 }
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                $rOperators = array('+','-','*','/');
                            }

             }

//display sequence having only single digit numbers
if($_POST['digits'] == 1)
     {
        $q = $_POST['que'];
             $previousInt = null;        //Track the previous operand
             $s = $_POST['select'];

                     for ($x = 1; $x<=$q; $x++) //for loop for no. of questions
                        {
                           $randomOperands = array();
                            $randomOperators = array();

                                    // loop over $i n times
                                   for ($i = 1; $i <=$s; $i++) //for loop for no. of integers user entered
                                     {
                                        $nextInt = rand(1, 9); // assign random operand to array slot
                                         $randomOperands[] = $nextInt;
                                            if($i < $s)
                                             {   
                                               if($previousInt === 0) //No operator after last opearnd
                                                  {
                                                 //avoid division-by-zero
                                                   $randomOperators[] = $rOperators[rand(0, 2)];
                                                  }
                                                else
                                                  {
                                                   $randomOperators[] = $rOperators[rand(0, $N-1)];
                                                  } 
                                              }  
                                        $previousInt = $nextInt;
                                      }
                                    // print array values
                                    $exp = '';     //Generating the expression
                                      foreach($randomOperands as $key=>$value1)
                                         {
                                          $exp .=  $value1 . " " ;  
                                             if(isset($randomOperators[$key]))
                                                {
                                                 $exp .=  $randomOperators[$key] ." "; 
                                                }
                                         }
                                         $res = eval("return ($exp);");//evaluate the expression 
                                           //print expression
                                        echo ("This is Q(".$x."):"), $exp."=". $res."<br>";
                          }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Adding some sensible code indentation would be a start. It will make the code _way_ more readable and will help both you and us to be able to follow the code and see what's going on.

Comment: You should also include examples of your current output and your expected output.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your reply, actually I am beginner in php. I have updated the screenshot of My current output and the screenshot of output that I am expecting.

Comment: can you please suggest me how should I do it ? I know we can use table structure  but I can't figure it out that how should it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the code in which you are generating the expression which you are using as the input to the `eval()` function. Create another string say `$output_string` which can be used to output your answer. In this newly created string use proper HTML tags along with the generated string, for formatting it the way you want your output to look like.

It should look something like this:

```
$exp = '';     //Generating the expression
$output_string = ''; // new string which can be used for generating the output string
foreach ( $randomOperands as $key => $value1 ) {
    $exp .=  $value1 . " " ;
    $output_string .=  $value1 . " <br>" ;
    if ( isset($randomOperators[$key]) ) {
        $exp .=  $randomOperators[$key] ." ";
        $output_string .=  $randomOperators[$key] ." <br> "; 
    }
}
$res = eval("return ($exp);");//evaluate the expression 
//print expression
echo ("This is Q(".$x."): <br>"), $output_string."= <br>". $res."<br>";
```

Comment: Hi, how can we display one question at a time for this , its working properly and generating all no of questions given  by user via  input field ? I added a button named "next" but how to code for it if  user clicked next ?

Comment: Keep the questions in different html elements, say on two different <div> elements. Set the style display: none; then onclick of a button use javascript to set the display: block;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27858174/display-a-div-on-button-click